# Show countdown in Chrome extension dropdown

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to show a countdown in my extension's drop-down but I have two problems:

A) My script returns an error because it cannot get the element by id from the drop-down's content

B) How do I keep the countdown running even if I close the drop-down and re-open it?

Here is my JS:

```
// variables for time units
var days, hours, minutes, seconds;

// get tag element
var countdown = document.getElementById("countdown");

// update the tag with id "countdown" every 1 second
setInterval(function () {

    // find the amount of "seconds" between now and target
    var current_date = new Date().getTime();
    var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;

    // do some time calculations
    days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
    seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;

    hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600);
    seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;

    minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
    seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);

    // format countdown string + set tag value
    countdown.innerHTML = days + "d, " + hours + "h, "
    + minutes + "m, " + seconds + "s";  

}, 1000);
```

And in the HTML I have:

```
<span id="countdown"></div>
```

The error I get is:
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null**

Any help is really appreciated! Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A) I suspect that your code is placed (inside a script which is placed) somewhere inside "head" part. In this case all you have to do is place all your code inside `window.onload = function () { ... }` or `DOMContentLoaded` listener

B) This is more complicated. I think the best solution is to create counter in background page and send messages from it to popup page every second.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry! In case of A) I placed the script within the body after the element is loaded which solved the issue. But I suspect your suggestion is just as good. In regards to B) I will give it a try and see if it works. Thanks for your help so far!